# How to stream a map with collection using Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream, multimap

I'd like to stream a map with collection using Java 8 streams.

For example, having the following data:

```
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> data;
```

I'd like to go over the elements handling each integer value with the corresponding key strings. For example:

```
data.keyValueStream((k,v)-> ...)
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks.

* Regarding the question "Why do you need it?", it could be a bunch of reasons and I'm not sure it's important. Anyhow, I'll "flow" with you... My specific scenario is to batch insert into a DB all the values, under their specific key. Let's keep it a general Java 8 stream question...

Comment: Proper solution may depend on what you really want to achieve. Can you explain what you need that pairs for?

Comment: `data.forEach((key1, value1) -> value1.forEach(item -> {
            System.out.println("Key:" + key1 + " value: " + item);
        }));`

Comment: Simplest and most efficient solution would just be to use a nested enhanced for loop IMHO.

Comment: Added an explanation to the question regarding the "Why you need the pair for?"

Comment: I guess that what I'm looking for doesn't exists. Mapping some collection to tuples and then working with the tuple values directly instead of a single wrapper object - doesn't exists in Java. It's always a single type stream.

Answer (score 5):

You can map your `Map<String, Collection<Integer>>` to `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`:

```
data.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new HashMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
  .forEach(e -> System.out.printf("key %s val %d%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

or:

```
data.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(n -> System.out.printf("key %s val %d%n", k, n)));
```

Comment: Why do `println(String.format("key %s, value %d",` instead of the shorter `printf("key %s, value %d%n",`?

Comment: @Andreas besides that, `flatMap` is eager until java-10, so if OP wants to short-circuit he cant; unlike a plain loop

Comment: @Andreas for two nested `forEach`, using `printf` is the simpler choice. For the stream using `flatMap`, it would make more sense to use `String.format`—instead of `new HashMap.SimpleEntry<>(…)` (which is a disguise, by the way, as the nested class is actually inherited from `AbstractMap` and unrelated to `HashMap`). I.e. `data.entrySet().stream()
  .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> String.format("key %s val %d%n", e.getKey(), v)))
  .forEach(System.out::print);`

Answer (score 3):

I realize that you ware asking about stream version, but **if you are NOT going to use parallelism** simplest and probably more efficient option would be using nested loops. This way you can avoid spending time and space on creating temporary instances for each `<Key,CollectionItem>` pair.

Instead you can use

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()){
    String key = entry.getKey();
    for (Integer number : entry.getValye()){
        //here we have access to <key, number> pair, 
        //handle them as you wish;
    }
}
```

Comment: But, but... Streams are new, so surely they are better than loops! (I sometimes despair that people forget that the old can be better).

Comment: @AndyTurner once the code is hot enough, the difference is tiny. Ive answered questions like these with proper JMH tests

Answer (score 2):

While this may be a bit obvious, you can also write:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(s -> System.out.println(k + "  " + s)))
```

Example, in Java 9.

```
Map< String , Collection< Integer > > map =
    Map.ofEntries(
        Map.entry( "alpha" , List.of( 1 , 2 , 3 ) ) ,
        Map.entry( "beta" , List.of( 4 , 5 , 6 ) ) ,
        Map.entry( "gamma" , List.of( 7 , 8 , 9 ) )
    )
;

map.forEach( ( k , v ) -> {
        v.forEach( s -> System.out.println( k + "  " + s ) );
    }
);
```

Comment: You don’t need `ofEntries` for such a short map. You can just use `Map.of("alpha", List.of(1, 2, 3), "beta", List.of(4, 5, 6), "gamma", List.of(7, 8, 9))`. Further, the nested `forEach` doesn’t need the statement syntax. So you can just use `map.forEach((k, v) -> v.forEach(s -> System.out.println(k + "  " + s)));`

Answer (score 1):

Streaming only processes a single value, so you can't get `keyValueStream((k,v)-> ...)`, but you can get `keyValueStream(x -> ...)` where `x` is a tuple/pair.

Since you are starting with a `Map`, which can stream `Entry` objects (key/value pairs), and you want a key/value pair in your lambda, a stream of `Entry` objects seems appropriate.

Which means that you just want to *flatten* the nested collection, e.g. like this:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
```

```
data.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream().map(v -> new SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), v)))
    // At this point you have a Stream<Entry<String, Integer>> so you can e.g. do this:
    .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + "=" + e.getValue()))
;
```